# my producer and consumer are not readable on Kafka using JMX

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx, jconsole

I set the Kafka on my localhost and then read the broker side using JVM and port 1999 but whatever I tried I can't reach my consumer or producer.
I am able to connect to port 9092 and read MBean on jconsole but I can't send any query to it using the python subprocess

I used the following JVM connection example "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1999/jmxrmi" and jmxquery/subprocess python libraries.

#### I wrote down every step I am doing in the repository

- https://github.com/mirkan1/kafka_monitoring.git

#### I am starting Kafka like this:

- https://github.com/mirkan1/kafka_monitoring/blob/master/start_kafka.sh

#### and starting consumers like this:

- https://github.com/mirkan1/kafka_monitoring/blob/master/start_consumer.sh

#### also the producer:

- https://github.com/mirkan1/kafka_monitoring/blob/master/start_producer.py

#### This is the main worker that I am trying to make work:

- https://github.com/mirkan1/kafka_monitoring/blob/master/kafka_consumer_watch.py

more info about what I am trying to accomplish is here: https://github.com/mirkan1/kafka_monitoring/tree/master/Kafka_Complete_Monitoring

Comment: Please include code in the question itself, not external links

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem was that I was using the same port which is 9092 for everything, after I assigned different ports for consumer and producer it worked at intended and I was able to read MBeans data using JMX connection